# How to type navigation in react-navigation library?

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation

I am using `react-navigation 5.5.1`, all is working great but I have some trouble with typescript.

I tried to type the `navigation` prop according to the docs (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/typescript/) but it looks like navigation is still type `any`.

Any clues what I missed?

```
export type AppParamList = {
  Intro: undefined;
  Stories: undefined;
};

interface RoutesProps {}

const Stack = createStackNavigator<AppParamList>();

const Routes: FC<RoutesProps> = () => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaProvider>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen name="Intro" component={Intro} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Stories" component={Stories} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </SafeAreaProvider>
  );
};

// Intro.tsx
import { StackNavigationProp } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { AppParamList } from ../

type IntroScreenNavigationProp = StackNavigationProp<AppParamList, 'Intro'>;

type Props = {
  navigation: IntroScreenNavigationProp;
};

const Intro = ({ navigation }: Props): ReactElement => (
  <SafeAreaView>
    <Text>Intro</Text>
    <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Stories')}>
      <Text>Go to stories</Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>
  </SafeAreaView>
);
```

[image]

Comment: Your screenshot codes look different than your pasted code.

Comment: You right. I took it out - not needed for this example. Anyway I was silly - the code works great I had to update my IDE.

Comment: I doubt if the problem is of IDE, `navigate(args: 'Storied')` is syntactically wrong. 
Either it should be `navigate('Storied')` or `navigate('Storied', {args: 'Storied'});`

Comment: args is part of webstorm visual code hinting. It is not actual code.

Comment: Ohh ok. Never used that, VSCode is <3

Comment: yeah I used VSCode - is great too! But I got free webstorm so couldn't resist :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was reproducing the issue using WebStorm 2019.2. I just updated to 2020.2 and now the warning is gone. I am assuming that was an issue with my IDE:)